# Geting a CASE statement to work with subquery/join

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL 5.6.

I have a query for a table `view_listInvoices` that has a column `state` which is an integer from 1-7, but as of now is mostly `NULL`.

What I'd like is to query for this state, and if it is some values, to display `---`, and if it is other values, to JOIN on a description table, `descinvoicestate` and display the description.

```
State        Desired Value
NULL         ----
1            descinvoice.description where view_listInvoice.state = descinvoicestate.idx
2            descinvoice.description where view_listInvoice.state = descinvoicestate.idx
3            descinvoice.description where view_listInvoice.state = descinvoicestate.idx
4            ---
5            ---
6            ---
7            descinvoice.description where view_listInvoice.state = descinvoicestate.idx
```

The `descinvoicestate` table is one of id's and a description column and thats it.

My current query which is not working is

```
SELECT
otherColumns...,
(SELECT CASE WHEN `view_listInvoices`.`state` IS NULL OR `view_listInvoices`.`state` IN (4, 5, 6) THEN "---"
ELSE (SELECT `descinvoicestate`.`description` 
FROM `view_listInvoices`  
JOIN `descinvoicestate`  
ON `descinvoicestate`.`idx` = `view_listInvoices`.`state`) END) as 'Prep'

FROM `view_listInvoices`
```

I keep getting that I have  syntax error but I don't know what is wrong.  Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `SELECT` in this manner with `CASE .. WHEN`. Also, you can utilize Correlated Subqueries here. Try the following instead:

```
SELECT
/* otherColumns..., */

CASE WHEN v.`state` IS NULL 
           OR v.`state` IN (4, 5, 6) 
     THEN '---' 
     ELSE ( SELECT d.description 
            FROM `descinvoicestate` AS d 
              ON d.`idx` = v.`state`
            LIMIT 1 ) 
     END as 'Prep'
FROM `view_listInvoices` AS v
```

Comment: I just figured it out and came up with exactly what you have.  Thank you.

Comment: @bjk116 . . . This is more complicated than necessary, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a select without nesting

```
SELECT
otherColumns...,
CASE WHEN `view_listInvoices`.`state` IS NULL OR `view_listInvoices`.`state` IN (4, 5, 6) 
    THEN "---"
    ELSE `descinvoicestate`.`description`
END   prep
FROM `view_listInvoices`  
JOIN `descinvoicestate`  ON `descinvoicestate`.`idx` = `view_listInvoices`.`stat
```

or if not all rows  nathc between the tables use left  join

```
SELECT
otherColumns...,
CASE WHEN `view_listInvoices`.`state` IS NULL OR `view_listInvoices`.`state` IN (4, 5, 6) 
    THEN "---"
    ELSE `descinvoicestate`.`description`
END   prep
FROM `view_listInvoices`  
LEFT JOIN `descinvoicestate`  ON `descinvoicestate`.`idx` = `view_listInvoices`.`stat
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT otherColumns...,
       COALESCE(dis.description, '---') as prep
END   prep
FROM `view_listInvoices` li LEFT JOIN
     `descinvoicestate` dis
     ON dis.`idx` = li.`stat;
```

This is a fairly common type of logic to implement.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for my specific use case as there are states that are not null that I still want to see a '---'.  However this is a good technique for some other aspects of my program so thanks.